# Understanding Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition

Tags: algorithm, math

I've been trying to read and understand the contents of this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

But I'm finding the contents to be challenging purely because I don't understand the mathematical or pseudo code notation. Are there any resources or books I should read / study in order to help me understand the content? I think I'm looking for the missing mathematical link in my life. I need something to bridge the gap between school and college level.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: If you post an example of a piece of psuedocode or mathematical notation, I am sure someone will walk through it with you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/what-is-the-best-book-for-studying-discrete-mathematics

Comment: Hunter: I wouldn't even know how to generate some of those symbols on my computer.

Comment: @hunter: I think this question is of a more general nature.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe go for a book where the examples are given in a specific language rather than pseudo-code.  e.g. Algorithms in C++ by Sedgewick is a grand book if you know C++.  Many of the older books tend to use Pascal like pseudo code, where Pascal isn't as common as it once was.

Being able run the code under a debugger, single stepped watching variables change, is also a great aid to understanding how the algorithm works.

Comment: Are there (still) good algorithms books that use SML? There was a time when I was seeing quite a few books using SML, which was nice because it is well-founded, and simple.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to read the first sections and the appendix at the end of the book, which has some mathematical background explained.

A good, not easy, but suitable for high school student, introduction to mathematics used in computer science is [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025), by Knuth, Graham & Patashnik.

Comment: On the second thought, I need to point, that Concrete Mathematics will be more helpful in understanding proofs and analysis than pseudocode. With pseudocode you have just get used to it (and start from the beginning of the book).

Comment: Concrete Mathematics is still rather difficult and somewhat beyond my math level!

Comment: You don't have to go through the whole book. I remember that generating functions were hard for me before I went to the university. Could you tell us more about your math background? Try to describe it.

Comment: I pretty much have zero math background outside of very basic high school.

Comment: Which doesn't mean anything, because I've no idea what they do in high schools in your country, and how long ago did you finished it, and what were the first things you couldn't undrstand on your own.

Comment: @RafałRawicki Concrete Mathematics is NOT highschool level at all!! #knuth